# Nested for each's looping through multi-dimensional array - how to do a conditional on the last value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

After a rollercoaster ride, I am "this" close to finalising a script I have been working on.

I have a multi-dimensional array stored in `$newarray` as below. I have built this array myself so the code to build it can be changed if needs be. But after creation I then loop through it picking out the values I want. I build a new array for each key in the upper array (3 in this case, 111, 222 & 333) and populate each with a a bunch of data objects from next array key down along with some other data.

However, what I need in the case below is to generate each of the 3 arrays (111, 222, 333) twice, once where the final array value = 0 ($the_action) and once where it = '1'. Where it = 1, print it, else where it = 0, do something else.

I also think that the way I loop through arrays with a single value in it is probably not very efficient, and the same goes for using key names as values.

Grateful for any help.

```
Array
(
    [111] => Array
        (
            [1234] => Array
                (
                    [100000] => Array
                        (
                            [20000] => 0
                        )

                )

            [1244] => Array
                (
                    [100001] => Array
                        (
                            [20001] => 1
                        )

                )

            [1255] => Array
                (
                    [100002] => Array
                        (
                            [20002] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [222] => Array
        (
            [1233] => Array
                (
                    [100013] => Array
                        (
                            [20013] => 0
                        )

                )

            [1241] => Array
                (
                    [100014] => Array
                        (
                            [20014] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [333] => Array
        (
            [15633] => Array
                (
                    [100026] => Array
                        (
                            [20026] => 0
                        )

                )
            [12144] => Array
                (
                    [100028] => Array
                        (
                            [20028] => 0
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

Code to build $newarray ($stack comes from CSV with 5 columns):

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($stack as $val){
    $lineid = $val[0]; $segmentid = $val[1]; $action = $val[2]; $recency = $val[3]; $frequency = $val[4];
    $newarray[$lineid][$segmentid][$recency][$frequency] = $action;
}
```

Code to loop through array:

```
foreach($newarray as $key => $value) {
    $target_pixels = array();
    $owner_id = $key;
    foreach($value as $key2 => $value2){
        $target_pixel = new stdClass;
        $target_pixel->conversion_id = $key2;
        $target_pixel->negated = false;
        foreach($value2 as $key3 => $value3){
            $target_pixel->seconds_since_conversion = $key3 * 24 * 60 * 60;
            foreach($value3 as $key4 => $value4){
                $target_pixel->frequency_min = $key4;
                $the_action = $value4;
            }
        }
        $target_pixels[] = $target_pixel;
    }
    print_r($target_pixels);
}
```

Comment: Will a "segmentid" ever have more than one "recency" and will a "recency" ever have more than one "frequency"? If not, it will almost certainly be easier to work with an array structure like `$array = array($lineid=>array($segmentid, $recency, $frequency));`.

Comment: No, they are unique - there is a 1:1:1 relationship between segmentid, frequency and recency. Frequency is shown as a child of recency only because of the way the array is put together. It's flawed but after working through it for so long, it works (at least until this point) and I am amazed I have got this far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you can change the structure of the array, I would go with something along the lines of:

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($stack as $val){
    $lineid = $val[0]; 
    $segmentid = $val[1]; 
    $action = $val[2]; 
    $recency = $val[3]; 
    $frequency = $val[4];
    $newarray[$lineid][$segmentid] = array(
        'recency' => $recency,
        'frequency' => $frequency
        'action' => $action
    );
}
```

Then your code would look like:

```
foreach ($newarray as $lineid => $line) {
    $target_pixels = array();
    $owner_id = $lineid;
    foreach ($line as $segmentid => $segment){
        $target_pixel = new stdClass;
        $target_pixel->conversion_id = $segmentid;
        $target_pixel->negated = false;
        $target_pixel->seconds_since_conversion = $segment['recency'] * 24 * 60 * 60;
        $target_pixel->frequency_min = $segment['frequency'];

        $target_pixels[$segment['action']][] = $target_pixel;
    }
    var_dump($target_pixels);
}
```

Comment: @Aether - var_dump - that's handy! Thanks again. Let me see if I understand the new code you are proposing. With regards to the conditional, the thing I don't get is where to place that conditional, because I don't just want to do something for each of the segmentid/recency/frequency combo, but (for the example - it could be any number) create 2 populated `$target_pixels` array for each unique `$lineid` - one containing segment_ids where action = 0 and one where action = 1. Cont...

Comment: ...In the example above, 3 arrays are created each containing a mix of 0's and 1's whereas I need 6 arrays, where the 1's are printed and the 0's I do something else with. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: @Dan If you need to do both actions for each array anyway, you could probably drop the `action` part altogether, then use the same set of arrays for the first action (printing) and the second action (whatever it is). If they need to be seperate (e.g. the second action involves manipulating them, but you want to original data to print later), you can copy the arrays and work with just the one copy.

Comment: @Aether - But each action (0 and 1) needs to be performed only for the relevant $segmentid's. Take array 111 for example - we need to create a $target_pixels array with two target_pixel data objects in it (segmentid 1234 and 1244), then do something, then create an another target_pixels array, this time just with one target_pixel data object in it.  Within each lineid, an action has to be performed on the 0's as a group and on the 1's as a group, before moving onto the next lineid. So it seems like the conditional would be after the first foreach and before the second, but I can't see how.

Comment: @Dan - Ah, I think that makes it a lot clearer for me! I'm just a little slow sometimes. :) Let's try again: I've updated my answer - now you get two arrays within the `$target_pixels` array with indicies `0` and `1` - these correspond to the arrays with action 0 and action 1. You can take the `$target_pixels[0]` array and do whatever with it (action 0), then take the `$target_pixels[1]` array and print it (action 1). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Aether - You are quicker than me on your slow days so don't beat yourself up ;-). That's perfect and works exactly right and better yet I understand it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Dan - Glad to help, and it's always better to have code you understand! :)